# Downloading emails via IMAP. Avoid dupes

Tags: imap, uid, messageid

I am developing simple program that will download my emails from different mail boxes and store in database for backup.

I plan to use IMAP and most mailboxes are gmail.

I am wondering how do I avoid dupes?

I read that `IMAP`'s `UID` is not reliable. 
`Message-ID` is not guaranteed to be unique.
Email's hash may change. 
(Some mail servers may modify emails header)

What is common and practical pattern usually used?

I do not wish to get tons of dupes and I do not wish to loose emails.

Also it would be automated script used for backup. I do not wish to manually verify it daily.

Comment: What is wrong with UIDs?  As long as you're in a single folder, UIDs have to be reliable or it is not possible to do any sort of persistent caching.    A full unique identifier for a message is the folder identifier, the UIDVALIDITY, and the UID: e.g. (INBOX:773827384:122).  You may need to track server and login name as well.

Comment: Max: Some/many versions of Exchange have odd behaviour with respect to UIDs. Othermax: All other current-day servers have sensible and reliable UIDs.

Comment: Oh, two Maxes.  That's confusing. Sorry :)